# い-Adjective Conjugation: かったです vs でした

Tags: grammar, conjugations, adjectives, i-adjectives, tense

When we first studied adjective conjugation in my Japanese class, I kept making the same mistake habitually; I would conjugate the past tense of い-adjectives with でした at the end instead of dropping the い and adding かったです. My teacher would correct me, and now I've more or less started doing かったです, but I still wonder about how "wrong" adjective-でした is.

> ○ あのテストは難しかったです。
>
> ×? あのテストは難しいでした。

Is the second sentence straight out wrong and/or extremely unnatural-sounding? Would anybody in Japan conjugate adjectives like this? Or does it possibly introduce a *slightly* different meaning?

Comment: Anyone would understand its meaning.  It is difficult to distinguish between “straight out wrong” and “extremely unnatural-sounding.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`あのテストは難しいでした` to me sounds strange. If you search Google for `テストは難しいでした`, you get about 10 results, many of them written by foreign speakers. `テストは難しかったです` however gets far more results.

I wouldn't right out say that it's wrong to use `難しいでした` as you can find many instances of it when you search for it. However, I think it's overwhelmingly used by females when you look through the results. It's just a speculation of mine, but it may sound slightly "cuter" or "younger" to use `難しいでした` as in `確かに難しいでしたけれどーー字の雰囲気で何となく解りましたから――ー大丈夫でした` and similar examples.

That said, I think people learning Japanese should use `難しかったです` rather than `難しいでした`.

**Disclaimer:** I'm not a native speaker, just my thoughts.

Answer (score 7):

It is ungrammatical. No one will conjugate like that.

Comment: If “anybody in Japan” in the question is interpreted as “educated speakers of the standard dialect of Japanese,” then I agree with you that no one will use that form.  However, “anybody in Japan” is too broad to say anything about them collectively.