# Most natural way to say "This movie was good"

Tags: english-to-japanese

この映画はよかったです.

or

この映画はいいでした.

My understanding is that they both have the same literal meaning. Is there a subtle difference between them? And, does it sound more natual to use one or the other?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3766/9831

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/35950/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43244/5010